# Por que Visual Studio 2013 não deixa usar versão 4 do Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Eu não sei por que, mas sempre que tento atualizar Object Model de um projeto antigo que temos, o Visual Studio 2013, pergunta se queremos manter a versão 4 da EF, mas mesmo marcando a versão certa ele atualiza e inclui referencias para versão 5.

Com a versão antiga isso não acontece, tanto que hoje tenho usado a outra versão como medida paliativa.

Pergunto:
Existe uma explicação para isso? Ou é um bug do aplicativo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a lista oficial de bugs conhecidos do Visual Studio 2013 Preview este bug em manter a versão do Entity Framework não consta na lista. [Veja a lista aqui](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2848395).

Porém esse pode ser um erro ainda não reportado (oficialmente). Na verdade ainda existem alguns erros em relação ao uso do EF no VS2013, como para algumas pessoas não há como gerar modelo visual às vezes. Você pode ver a lista completa de feedbacks (e bugs reportados) relacionados do Visual Studio com o Entity framework [aqui](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=Entity%20Framework).

Uma possível correção é instalar as [Tools do Entity Framework para o Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) ou o [update do Visual Studio](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911573).

Aqui existe uma pergunta sobre como forçar usar o EF4 no Visual Studio 2013... e, bem, apagar dlls, usar T4... pode te ajudar a contornar o problema de imediato: [veja pergunta e resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923156/how-to-use-entity-framework-4-with-visual-studio-2013).

Boa sorte.

**ATENÇÃO, IMPORTANTE ADICIONAL DE INFORMAÇÕES:**

Eu estive tuitando com Julie Lerman e outras pessoas fantásticas que trabalham com Entity Framework quando Jiri Cintura [nos mandou](https://twitter.com/julielerman/status/433587968918683648) um link sobre esse problema, [leia aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/data/dn440683).

Eu acabei esquecendo dessa alternativa, desculpe, mas é simples: instalar pelo Nuget a versão 4 do Entity Framework.

O Visual Studio 2013 já vem com o Nuget Console, você só precisa ir até ele e digitar o seguinte código:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -version 4.3.0
```

Isso vai instalar no seu projeto a versão 4.3.0, se quiser outra versão é só alterar o 4.3.0 pelo número que deseja.

Isso com certeza vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: obrigado pelos links. Sobre a solução do stackoverflow americano acho que não vale a pena, já que o problema se repete a cada atualização. Se atualização da EF Tools não funcionar, continuarei usando VS2012 para isso.

Comment: que isso, tamo aqui pra nos ajudarmos, Cleiton. Uma pena ninguém conhecer esse bug. Falei com a Julie Lerman e com outros feras e ninguém nunca ouviu falar desse bug. Se você me permitir eu gostaria de adicionar esse feedback na lista oficial.